# How do you run two different functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two different javascript functions as below. When I call these functions, until the function completes executing, I am showing loading image. The problem I am having is that when first function completes, it should load the chart and the second function runs and load the chart.

That's not what's happening. Both charts load when both function completes. I need each function to run and load the chart when each complete not both at the same time.

Here is the functions:

```
<script>

  function vcenter1(){

    $('#loading').html('<img src="img/loading.gif"> loading...');

    var req = ocpu.rpc("cpu", {

    }, function(output){
      var data=output;
      data=JSON.parse(data);
        $('#output').highcharts('StockChart', {      
          chart: {
            borderColor: '#98AFC7',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderWidth: 1,
            renderTo: 'output',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 30,
            zoomType: 'x',
            resetZoomButton: {
              position: {

                x: -50,
                y: -40
              }
            }
          },
          plotOptions: {
            line: {
              marker: {
                radius: 2,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 2
              }
            }
          },

          exporting: {
            enabled: true
          },
          legend: {
            enabled:true,
            layout: 'horizontal',

            maxHeight: 55 // max. 2 lines with navigation
        },
          rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            inputEnabled: $('#output').width() > 480,
            selected: 2
          },
          scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
                    },
            navigator : {
                enabled : false
            },

          xAxis: {
            type:'datetime',
            gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',
            gridLineWidth: 1
          },
           yAxis: { // Primary yAxis
                    min:0,
                    max:100,
            labels: {

                style: {
                    color: "black",
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '% CPU Utilization',
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }


        },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },

          title: {
            text: "% CPU UTILIZATION",
            style: {
              color: '#333000',
              fontSize: '18px',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
          },


         tooltip: {
                      useHTML:true,
                      positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                        return { x: this.chart.plotLeft, y: this.chart.plotTop - 5 };
                      },
                  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} <b>',
                  valueDecimals: 0
                },
          series: data
        });
      });

      //if R returns an error, alert the error message
      req.fail(function(){
        alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
        $('#loading').html('');
      });

      //after request complete, re-enable the button 
      req.always(function(){
         $('#loading').html('');

      });
}

//VCENTER2

function vcenter2(){

    $('#loading1').html('<img src="img/loading.gif"> loading...');

    var req = ocpu.rpc("memory", {

    }, function(output1){
      var data1=output1;
      data1=JSON.parse(data1);
      console.log("Ready to paint 2:");
        $('#output1').highcharts('StockChart', {      
          chart: {
            borderColor: '#98AFC7',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderWidth: 1,
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 20,
            zoomType: 'x',
            resetZoomButton: {
              position: {

                x: -50,
                y: -40
              }
            }
          },
          plotOptions: {
            line: {
              marker: {
                radius: 2,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 2
              }
            }
          },

          exporting: {
            enabled: true
          },
          legend: {
            enabled:true,
            layout: 'horizontal',

            maxHeight: 55 // max. 2 lines with navigation
        },
          rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            inputEnabled: $('#output1').width() > 480,
            selected: 2
          },
          scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
                    },
            navigator : {
                enabled : false
            },

          xAxis: {
            type:'datetime',
            gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',
            gridLineWidth: 1
          },
           yAxis: { // Primary yAxis
                min:0,
                max:100,
            labels: {

                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '% Memory Utilization',
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },

          title: {
            text: "% MEMORY UTILIZATION",
            style: {
              color: '#333000',
              fontSize: '18px',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
          },


         tooltip: {
                      useHTML:true,
                      positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                        return { x: this.chart.plotLeft, y: this.chart.plotTop - 5 };
                      },
                  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} <b>',
                  valueDecimals: 0
                },
          series: data1
        });
      });

      //if R returns an error, alert the error message
      req.fail(function(){
        alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
        $('#loading1').html('');
      });

      //after request complete, re-enable the button 
      req.always(function(){
         $('#loading1').html('');
      });
}

</script>
```

This is where I am calling them:

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script>
      $('a[href*="vmware"]').on('click', function () {

    vcenter1();
    vcenter2();

});
```

Any ideas that I am missing here? I need to show loading image why the function is running, when it's completes, I need to show the data and move on to the second function and so forth. Now, what's happening is that first function runs, completes, loading image goes away but no data/chart shows up. Second function runs, completes then both divs are full with data/charts.

Comment: This is a wall of code man, and not properly formatted. Please put some effort into formatting your code and finding the problem section before posting to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at JavaScript callbacks, or for more functionality, jQuery Deferred - a good tutorial is at http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/.

Comment: it sounds like Deferred waits for both functions to complete. I need each function run, show data and continue on. Dont wait for every function to complete.

Comment: You can set up Deferred for one function and when it completes, call the next.

Comment: it is not really what I was asking. It's ok that both function run at the same time. When a function completes, I need the output show up, no need to wait for other functions to complete.

Comment: Then try using JavaScript callbacks, take a look at [this link](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Comment: I thought I am using callback already,  $('a[href*="vmware"]').on('click', function () {

Comment: No, I mean give the function `vcenter1()` a callback to load `vcenter2()`. Whilst I haven't seen all your code, there are several CSS ways to achieve vertical centering, see [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

Comment: sorry I am very new to this stuff, can you start me?

Comment: Start a new question if you want an answer about JavaScript callbacks or CSS vertical centering.

Comment: When @Zak said to ask another question he didn't mean to ask the [same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532750/how-do-you-run-two-javascript-functions-independently#25532750).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how the asynchronous calls are working.  With your functions here's how the workflow would go:

```
vcenter1
rpc
async ajax call to R
vcenter2
rpc 
async ajax call to R
```

At some later time, vcenter1's ajax call completes, then -->

```
always callback - which removes loading
complete callback
parse JSON
render chart
```

At some later time, vcenter2's ajax call completes, then -->

```
always callback - which removes loading
complete callback
parse JSON
render chart
```

If you *really* want it to run vcenter2 after vcenter1, then the call to vcenter2 needs to be in the complete callback of vcenter1's rpc.

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing. The problem I am eperiencing is this. venter1 completes but no data, vcenter2 completes then I see data from both function. I really dont know what's happening.