# how do you run two javascript functions independently

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript functions:

```
vcenter1();
vcenter2();
```

I need this functions to run a dropdown click event independent of each other.

I have this piece of code:

```
$('a[href*="vmware"]').on('click', function () {
    vcenter1();
    vcenter2();
});
```

When I click the dropdown menu, the functions load but they load at the same time. I need these functions to load independent of each other. How could I do this?

Here is the original question:

[this was the original question on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530054/how-do-you-run-two-different-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: They don't load at the same time. `vcenter1` loads slightly earlier.

Comment: "I need this functions to run a dropdown click event independent of each other." - what does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? What do you mean by "independent of each other"? What do the functions do?

Comment: Javascript has only one thread, unless the functions are async, they run in the order they are encountered, no magic !

Comment: The problem is with how those functions are coded, not how you call them. But without details not knowing what you are really after, your question is nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: may be there is a better way . what does these functions do?

Comment: @tcooc, yes, that's what the intention but that's not what's happening. I looked at the chrome console, 1st function executes then waits for the second function, after second functions completes, I see the data for both functions. I am trying to find a solution where each function call is independent of each other, 1st function runs and loads and then second function.

Comment: I think you're looking for [callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Comment: Still not getting what you mean by "load" vs. "run". Please show us the code for the functions in question. Is it an asynchronicity question?

Comment: @torazaburo, I updated the post with the original question.

Comment: Sorry, nobody is going to dig through all that code to try to figure out what you are asking. Please consult the posting guidelines. You need to post a minimal, stripped-down code which gives all pertinent information necessary for people that look at your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run two different functions in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530054/how-do-you-run-two-different-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the second function after the first asynchronous request is done.

At the end of your `vcenter1`, add:

```
return req;
```

Then modify your code to:

```
$('a[href*="vmware"]').on('click', function () {
    vcenter1().then(vcenter2);
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but still seeing the same, no change.

Comment: this works for running one function at a time. How would I modify this so that both function runs at the same time?

Comment: @user1471980 Your original code runs both at the same time.

Comment: yes it looks like it is running but I dont get anything back from vcenter1() until vcenter2() completes running. It is very strange.

Comment: @user1471980 If you run both at the same time, the faster one will complete first. The order you call them makes little to no difference.

Comment: I really appreciate your trying to help me. I have one question. In my original post, I am showing loading image while the function vcenter1() and 2 running, as this:  $('#loading').html('<img src="img/loading.gif"> loading...'); I see that loading image goes away on the first function call vcenter1() but I dont see any data that should be returned by vcenter1() until the second function vcenter2() completes.

Comment: @user1471980 That is out of scope for this question. If you have follow up questions that deal with other aspects of the code please ask a new question, rather than asking in the comments.